# Can't connect Samsung Galaxy Ace S5830 to PC after root

Tags: connection-issues, samsung-galaxy-ace

I have a Samsung S5830 phone. After I rooted it using upd-1.zip I got a superuser icon in the app list. However my PC won't recognize it. I have Kies installed and all Samsung drivers but it seems the problem is not with the drivers, what should I do?

Answer (score 3):

Your phone might be going into USB Debugging Mode on connecting to PC. After phone is connected to PC via cable, disable Debugging Mode [`Settings -> Applications -> Development`] and then check for Kies Connection.

My friend had the same issue and we resolved it like this.